# I am wanting to make each variable in my array = 0 in vb

Tags: vb.net

I have been looking all over the internet looking for a solution and can't find any but I want to make each variable in my array which is double = 0 for a clear button on my form, after i run the loop the array values still have their orginal value the array and their variables inside them are declared as global variables.  here is my code whch is ran inside the button event procedure:

```
Dim intCount As Integer
For intCount = 0 To (dblTotals.Length - 1)
    dblTotals(intCount) = 0
Next intCount
```

i Have also tried this in the body of the code    dblTotals(intCount) -= dblTotals(intCount)

but still has the same amount when the loop is finsihed
I have also tried a do while loop and a for each loop and they still have their same value

Comment: By "doesn't seem to be working" do you mean they still have their original values after the loop?

Comment: Please add more context at your code. Where and how do you declare the array? Where do you call this code? I have no problem with these lines to set an array of doubles to zero

Comment: All your previous questions have negative scores (and bad titles); on this one `doesnt seem to be working` is a bad problem description.  Do read [ask] and take the [tour] soon -- you have to be knocking on the door of being throttled how often you can ask questions (or banned).

Comment: Sorry I am only new to this, in a panic as have a deadline on this program and this is just bugging me, i could clear each variable by setting each one indivdually as 0 but think this method would ear me more marks, sorry for the bad question

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `Array.Initialize()`:

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.initialize(v=vs.110).aspx
>
> Initializes every element of the value-type Array by calling the default constructor of the value type.

```
Dim arr As New Double( 10 )
' Note that Arrays are already instantiated with all-zero (default) values.

' Set some values:
arr(1) = 123.45
arr(9) = 456

' Now zero it
arr.Initialize()

Assert.AreEqual( 0, arr(9) )
```

Comment: What is Assert.AreEqual is seems to be throwing an error everything i try to write it

Comment: @AaronCoyle `Assert.AreEqual` is present in most unit-testing frameworks, I included it in my code sample to illustrate that `arr(9)` will be reset to zero.